# How to select two columns in one int array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a data  list and I want to make an array of two columns like-

```
var array= dataList.Select(a => a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId).ToArray();
```

Please suggest what is the correct way to make a array of two or more columns in entity framework.

**Update**

I also tried following.

```
var array= dataList.Select(a => new { a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId }).ToArray();
```

This gives result as follows

[image]

But I need result as follows.

```
[0] 5145
[1] 5155
[2] 5146
[3] 5149
```

Thanks.

Comment: var array= dataList.Select(a => new {  a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId }).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var array = dataList.SelectMany(a => new int[] { a.EmployerId, a.CustomerId }).ToArray();
```

This will give you result as follows

```
[0] 5145
[1] 5155
[2] 5146
[3] 5149
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) for this purpose:

```
var array= dataList.Select(a => new {a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId}).ToArray();
```

or as an another solution create a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var array= dataList.Select(a => new Person{ CustomerId = a.CustomerId, EmployerId  = a.EmployerId}).ToArray();
```

And based on your EDIT you want to flatten the array, so you need to change the `Select` to [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and also `new` to `new[]`, like this:

```
var array = dataList.SelectMany(a => new int[] { a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId}).ToArray();
```

Comment: @AshokKumawat So you want to flatten the array, you need to change the `Select` to `SelectMany` and also `new` to `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use dynamic

```
var array= dataList.Select(a => new {  a.CustomerId, a.EmployerId }).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's not dynamic, that's an anonymous class.